# How do I make xmonad use a haskell-based xmobar?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, configuration, xmonad, xmobar

##### tl;dr

How do I change this `xmonad.hs`,

```hs
import XMonad
main :: IO ()
main = xmonad def { terminal = "urxvt" , modMask = mod4Mask }
```

in order for XMonad to spawn xmobar correctly (spawn once, and kill and re-spawn if I restart XMonad in place, and any other sensible requirement) without an `xmobarrc` config file but with an actual `xmobar.hs` Haskell file containing the following?

```
import Xmobar
main :: IO ()
main = xmobar defaultConfig { commands = [Run XMonadLog], template = "%XMonadLog%" }
```

---

##### More datails

From [XMonad tutorial](https://xmonad.org/TUTORIAL.html) I read

> It is also possible to completely configure xmobar in Haskell, just like xmonad. If you want to know more about that, you can check out the [xmobar.hs](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/etc/xmobar.hs) example in the official documentation. For a more complicated example, you can also check out [jao’s xmobar.hs](https://codeberg.org/jao/xmobar-config) (he’s the current maintainer of xmobar).

In the file at the first link, the instruction is

```hs
-- An example of a Haskell-based xmobar. Compile it with
--   ghc --make -- xmobar.hs
-- with the xmobar library installed or simply call:
--   xmobar /path/to/xmobar.hs
-- and xmobar will compile and launch it for you and
```

and I have verified that indeed executing `ghc --make xmbobar.hs` (GHC 9.4.8) generates an `xmobar` executable that, when executed, spawns the bar (`xmobar /path/to/xmobar.hs` instead just never returns).

But what is the proper way to tell XMonad to run `xmobar`?

From the first link in the quote above, I can get [here](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/using-haskell.org), where I read

> Or put your `xmobar.hs` program in `~/.config/xmobar/xmobar.hs` and, when running the system-wide `xmobar`, it will notice that you have your own implementation and (re)compile and run it as needed.

but I still don't know how to have XMobar do the "running system-wide `xmobar`".

---

##### Some more finding

I think I've got to a minimal *working* example, but I don't really understand quite a few details.

Given this `~/.config/xmonad/xmonad.hs`,

```hs
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Hooks.StatusBar.PP
import XMonad.Util.Run

main :: IO ()
main = do
     xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar ~/.config/xmonad/xmobar.hs"
     xmonad . ewmhFullscreen
            . ewmh
            $ myConfig xmproc

myConfig h = def
    { terminal = "urxvt"
    , modMask = mod4Mask
    , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
    { ppOutput = hPutStrLn h
    }
    }
```

and this `~/.config/xmonad/xmobar.hs`,

```hs
import Xmobar

config :: Config
config = defaultConfig
    {
      commands =
        [ Run StdinReader,
          Run $ Date "%a %_d %b %Y <fc=#ee9a00>%H:%M:%S</fc>" "date" 10
        ],
      template = "%StdinReader% }{ %date%",
      alignSep = "}{"
    }

main :: IO ()
main = xmobar config
```

the two seem to work fine together.

However, below is what I don't understand.

- [The tutorial](https://xmonad.org/TUTORIAL.html) mentions a problem I don't really understand yet,

  > It is thus much better to switch over to property based logging, where we are writing to an X11 property and having xmobar read that; no danger when things are not being read!

  but most importantly it concludes that

  > For this reason we have to use `XMonadLog` instead of `StdinReader` in our xmobar.

  But as you can see, in the `xmobar.hs` above, I use `StdinReader`; if I plainly substitute that with `XMonadLog` *without doing any other change anywhere (and I think I should instead do something in `xmobar.hs` to make the change work)* then two things happen:

  - the selected work-space will not reflect anymore what workspace I'm in,
  - and restarting XMonad via <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> results in the one more `xmobar` process to be spawned, without the previous one being killed (in other words, once more I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, one more pid is shown by `pidof xmobar`).
- <s>In the `xmonad.hs` there a line that doesn't look right to me</s>

  ```hs
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar ~/.config/xmonad/xmobar.hs"
  ```

  If I'm using XMobar as a library, then why am I running the `xmobar` executable (which is at `/home/enrico/.cabal/bin/xmobar`) passing to it the path to my `xmobar.hs` instead of just spawning the executable *I* have compiled?

  Well, going back to [this](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/etc/xmobar.hs), I think that probably makes sense:

  > ```hs
  > -- An example of a Haskell-based xmobar. Compile it with
  > --   ghc --make -- xmobar.hs
  > -- with the xmobar library installed or simply call:
  > --   xmobar /path/to/xmobar.hs
  > -- and xmobar will compile and launch it for you and
  > ```
- The bar doesn't impose an offset to the windows, so the windows partly cover the bar

  [image]

  and for the life of me, I can't really find how to prevent that; the same thing doesn't happen with the `xmobarrc` approach.

Comment: I've modified the question to include what I think is the minimal xmobar code that retains all the interesting complications. Of course roll it back or update it if you think I haven't caught the bits that matter.

Comment: @DanielWagner, well thanks for that, no problem. I've updated the question to add some more info about what else I've tried so far. I've got a bit forward, but still can't use that bar instead of the `xmobarrc`-configured bar.

Comment: It's great you've made progress, nice work! What's the status of this question now? Is your answer a complete answer, or are there still pieces that aren't working right?

Comment: @DanielWagner, for now it is the answer. I'll keep experimenting a bit more before self-accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my mistake consisted in think that moving from one approach (`xmonad.hs` + `xmobarrc`), call it A, to the other approach  (`xmonad.hs` + `xmobar.hs`), call it B, I was also removing the usage of `withEasySB`,

```hs
     . withEasySB (statusBarProp (unwords ["xmobar", xmobarhs]) (pure myXmobarPP)) toggleStrutsKey
```

to launch xmobar and just using `spawnPipe` (as shown in the question), thinking that with the approach B the configuration of xmobar was all up to `xmobar.hs`.

Apparently, I've misunderstood the way XMonad and XMobar are supposed to work together:

- XMobar can do and does some things on its own (e.g. showing the date, or other data that has nothing to do with window management),
- whereas it has to receive from XMonad information about window management, and that's what `%XMonadLog%` is for.
- Additionally, it's XMonad that has to deal with the fact that XMobar can or cannot be overlapped by other windows or not.